# PHP CURl без внешки

Tags: php, nginx, curl

В нашей стране очень ограничен внешний трафик либо частенько отваливается. 
Есть сервер внутренний, NGINX. На нем есть сайт. При открытии сайта выполняются два запроса: первый запрос отправляется на этот сервер, который в свою очередь через CURL обращается к серверу Гугл для запроса аналитики, второй запрос, по таймеру, раз в 5 сек. проверяет наличие уведомлений в БД.

Когда на сервере есть доступ к внешнему трафику, то все в порядке. Проблемы начинаются, когда на сервере отваливается внешний трафик: тот запрос, что идет на аналитику, блокирует все остальные запросы, те что по таймеру.

Запрос на аналитику, а также последующие на проверку уведомлений висят в консоли со статусом "(pending)"

Также было замечено, что если запрос на аналитику завершается с ошибкой 500, последующие запросы отрабатывают корректно. Если же запрос на аналитику завершился с ошибкой 504, то и все последующие запросы завершаются с ошибкой 504

Есть ли способ решить данную неприятность, или способ проверить, есть ли доступ к внешнему трафику.

Всем спасибо заранее

Comment: попробуйте таймауты соединения curl_setopt CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT 1 или CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS

Comment: найдите почему блокируются параллельные запросы. Возможно из-за открытой сессии `session_start`. Ну и таймауты на сетевые операции

Comment: @noname2019, мы пробовали так, но теперь загвоздка в том, что если доступ к внешки есть, скрипт может не успеть получить данные за 1 сек

Comment: @Мелкий, не могли бы вы подсказать, где искать?

Comment: Вплоть до с gdb пристать к процессу php и почитать backtrace. Но начните с проверки сессий, это довольно частая причина выстраивания очереди запросов к php от одного браузера. Не надо держать сессию дольше необходимого.

Comment: @Мелкий, можете немного прояснить, как влияют сессии на это дело?

Comment: потому что https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3/ext/session/mod_files.c#L214 От session_start до session_write_close может выполняться только один скрипт. Если скрипт висит с обращением по сети - никакой другой скрипт с этим session id выполняться не будет. Простой блокировочник для сериализации доступа потенциально многих конкурентно пишущих в одну сессию. Если вам в этом скрипте сессия нужна только на чтение - то можно так же воспользоваться опцией read_and_close у session_start

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Проверяем доступность
$url = 'https://site_for_out.com';
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '10');
$fp = fopen($url, "r");
$res = fread($fp, 500);
fclose($fp);
if (strlen($res) > 0) {
//делаем что-то - например, выполняем тот же запрос к тому же ресурсу
}
```

Comment: Протестировали. С вашим кодом, точь в точь. Но опять же, проблема не решилась, просто стало времени меньше тратиться на обработку запроса. Ранее запрос обрабатывался столько, скольку указано в конфигах, теперь столько сколько указано в ini_set('default_socket_timeout');

Comment: Ну, тогда у Вас вопрос несколько иной, наверное - Вы написали, что "когда отваливается внешний трафик" - если доступность ни при чем, то тогда не об отвале трафика, видимо речь должна идти - причина и проблема в другом, думается.